# What is the function/ part of speech of "welcoming many visitors?"

Tags: parts-of-speech, semantic-roles

What is the function/ part of speech of "welcoming many visitors" in the sentence below?

> The United States is flinging its doors wide open to vaccinated international travelers on Monday, **welcoming many visitors** who've been shut out of the country for 20 months.

Comment: I'd say it's effectively just a "parallel construction" implicitly repeating the initial Subject + Verb - which could have been *explicitly* repeated in the context of a separate sentence: *The United States is flinging its doors wide open ... on Monday. **The United States is** welcoming many visitors...* But you might prefer to describe it as a *[continuous] **participial adverbial clause***.

Comment: It's category (your part of speech) is 'gerund-participial clause'. Functionally, the comma after "Monday" marks it as a supplementary adjunct, a loosely attached expression set off by intonation and (here) punctuation presenting supplementary non-integrated content.